# Postgres Docker container does not run create SQL script

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, postgresql-9.3

`docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: "postgres"
    build: .
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    env_file:
      - database.env
```

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM postgres:9.3
ADD CreateDB.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

`CreateDB.sql`

```sql
CREATE TABLE data_actions (
    username VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    json_payload VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    cache_id VARCHAR,
    action_timestamp TIMESTAMP
)
```

`database.env`

```sh
DOCKER_USER=docker
DOCKER_DB=docker
DOCKER_PASSWORD=docker
```

These are the files I'm using to create this container.  I've verified that the CreateDB.sql script is copied into the container and is in the correct location.  When I build and run the container and check pgAdmin, there are no tables in the docker database.  I feel like I'm missing something obvious here?

**UPDATE**
Here are the logs from startup ->

```
LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2020-12-23 18:21:18 UTC
LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
LOG:  record with zero length at 0/17A7030
LOG:  redo is not required
LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
LOG:  received smart shutdown request
LOG:  autovacuum launcher shutting down
```

Comment: Is that your full compose file? No volumes defined? If you did define a volume, did it already exist when you run your most recent test?

Comment: @BMitch it initially had volumes defined but i've since pruned and removed the images and containers and rebuilt entirely.

Comment: Have you checked the container logs to see if there are any messages related to that script?

Comment: I wasn't running it in the background but I'll update the post with logs

Comment: Never mind, I spotted your problem.

Comment: Also, +1 for providing all the information necessary in this question to reproduce the problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have misnamed your environment variables.  The [postgres image](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres) expects the environment names to begin with `POSTGRES_` (so, `POSTGRES_DB`, `POSTGRES_USER`, etc).

After renaming things in `database.env` so that I have:

```
POSTGRES_USER=docker
POSTGRES_DB=docker
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=docker
```

I can start your compose stack and then:

```
$ docker-compose exec db psql -U docker
psql (9.3.25)
Type "help" for help.

docker=# \c docker
You are now connected to database "docker" as user "docker".
docker=# \dt
           List of relations
 Schema |     Name     | Type  | Owner
--------+--------------+-------+--------
 public | data_actions | table | docker
(1 row)

docker=#
```

With your original `database.env`, Postgres would have created your `data_actions` table in the default `postgres` database.

Comment: Thanks!  This solved my problem, but in case anyone stumbles across this, I pruned the containers and it still wasn't running the script.  I had to rebuild without cache.